# Add/ delete rows based on value counts of certain column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given the below dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [ "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4"],
    "Feature": [ 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 6, 3, 5, 7, 1]
})
```

such that if the value count of certain ID is less than 4 (e.g. value count of ID 2,3,4 are 2,3,2 respectively), then copy the last row that appears for that ID and pad it so that the value count of that ID becomes 4,
and if the value count of certain ID is greater than 4 (e.g. value count of ID 1 is 5), then delete the last rows that appears for that ID so that the value count of that ID becomes 4.

So given the above dataframe:

```
          ID Feature
0         1  2
1         1  6
2         1  4
3         1  5
4         1  6
5         2  3
6         2  1
7         3  6
8         3  3
9         3  5
10        4  7
11        4  1
```

the outcome should be

```
          ID Feature
0         1  2
1         1  6
2         1  4
3         1  5
4         2  3
5         2  1
6         2  1
7         2  1
8         3  6
9         3  3
10        3  5
11        3  5
12        4  7
13        4  1
14        4  1
15        4  1
```

Is there any efficient way/ vectorized way to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandawheres.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='ffill'` for filter and add values to `MultiIndex` created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), last remove helper level in `MultiIndex`:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['ID'].unique(), range(4)], names=['ID','g'])
df = (df.set_index(['ID','g'])
        .reindex(mux, method='ffill')
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   ID  Feature
0   1        2
1   1        6
2   1        4
3   1        5
4   2        3
5   2        1
6   2        1
7   2        1
8   3        6
9   3        3
10  3        5
11  3        5
12  4        7
13  4        1
14  4        1
15  4        1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could [craft a MultiIndex from a product](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandawheres.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), this will limit the number of rows to 4, then [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to add the missing values:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['ID'].unique(), range(4)], names=['ID', ''])

(df.set_index(['ID', df.groupby('ID').cumcount()])
   .reindex(idx)
   .ffill(downcast='infer')
   .droplevel(1)
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   ID  Feature
0   1        2
1   1        6
2   1        4
3   1        5
4   2        3
5   2        1
6   2        1
7   2        1
8   3        6
9   3        3
10  3        5
11  3        5
12  4        7
13  4        1
14  4        1
```

Comment: ya, really similar, only I use `method='ffill'` and you `ffill` :)

Comment: @jezrael great minds think alike :p +1 to you ;)

Comment: add `ID` to names for prevent `index` column